# Dynamics of $x \log x$

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems, entropy

I came across this dynamical system on $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$: consider the group homomorphism $$\mathbb{R}_{>0} \longrightarrow \rm{Diff}(\mathbb{R}_{>0})$$
which sends $\alpha$ to $x^\alpha$. Composing with the isomorphism of topological groups $\mathbb{R}_{>0} \sim (\mathbb{R},+)$ (given by the exponential) this gives a continuous dynamical system $$\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \rm{Diff}(\mathbb{R}_{>0})$$
whose associated vector field (on $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$) is $x \textrm{log} x$.

The question is: has anyone heard about such a dynamical system? Is there any literature about it, has it got a name? What can you tell me about it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Never heard of it, but it is explicit and quite simple ($e^{e^{c+t}}$, a possible form of writing it). So you can compute everything. Not entropy though (as your tags seem to suggest), since the space is not compact (and so entropy is not defined).